# Render a view as response of Event Broadcasting

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-5.5

Hi there i'm under development of a Laravel webapp that use events broacasting troug redis, and socket.io. All is working fine, but i tring to return a rendered view as response of Event.
Mi event is something like this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class EventName implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> 'Funziona',
            'view'=> view('dashboard.partials.messages')->render()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

and i use this code to render response on the page:

```
<script src="/frontend/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://1clickfashion.com:3002');
            socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function(message){
            // increase the power everytime we load test route
            alert(message.data.power);
            $('#messages').html('');
            $('#messages').html(message.data.view);

        });
    </script>
```

The "power" alert is displayed correctly but the view don't work as well. In another view i'm use the view as `return response()->json($view)` and works perfectly... Someone have similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that struggle in this issue, solved by passing the view as variable rendered in Controller. Like this.

In Controller:

```
$view = view('dashboard.partials.messages')->with('post', $post_c)->render();
        event(new \App\Events\Post($view));
```

in event:

```
 public $data;

    public function __construct($view)
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'view'=> $view
        );
    }
```